# problemas con filter de mat angular

Tags: angular, filtro, angular-material, busqueda

estoy teniendo problemas con la busqueda  en una tabla de angular material con el elemento filter adjunto codigo e imagenes

```html
<div class="container p-3">
  <div class="row px-3">
    <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="payments.length < 1">
      <!--loader-->
      <div class="text-center">
        <img src="assets/gift/loader.gif" alt="loader">
      </div>
      <p class="text-center">
        Cargando Data
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--Table-->
    <div class="text-danger" >agregar usuario con boton colocar aki</div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mat-elevation-z2 p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded" *ngIf="payments.length > 0">
      <div class="pt-5 ">
        <p class="text-center fs-2 text-decoration-underline">
          Lista de Facturas Actuales:
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
          <mat-label>Buscar</mat-label>
          <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Ej. jugo" #input>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="border mat-elevation-z2">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
        
          <!-- date Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Fecha: </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let payment"> {{payment.createdAt | date:'M/d/yy, h:mm a'}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <!-- name Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="name" class="d-flex">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Cliente: </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let payment"> {{payment.client.name}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <!-- client_ci Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="client_ci">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ci: </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let payment"> {{payment.client.ci}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <!-- products Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="products">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Productos: </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let payment">
              <div *ngFor="let product of payment.Product_Payments">
                  {{product.paidProduct.name + ':' + ' ' + product.product_qty + ' ' + 'uds'}}
              </div>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
          <!-- sub_total Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="sub_total">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Sub total: </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let payment">{{payment.sub_total}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <!-- total Column-->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="total">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Total: </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let payment">{{payment.total}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <!-- status Column-->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Estado: </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let payment">
              <span *ngIf="payment.status == false" class="text-danger">
                deuda
              </span>
              <span *ngIf="payment.status == true" class="text-success">
                pago
              </span> 
            </td>
          </ng-container>
          <!-- CONFIRM Column-->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="confirm">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> - </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let payment">
              <a *ngIf="payment.status == false" matTooltip="Confirmar Pago" matTooltipClass = "tooltipPer">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-check-lg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path d="M12.736 3.97a.733.733 0 0 1 1.047 0c.286.289.29.756.01 1.05L7.88 12.01a.733.733 0 0 1-1.065.02L3.217 8.384a.757.757 0 0 1 0-1.06.733.733 0 0 1 1.047 0l3.052 3.093 5.4-6.425a.247.247 0 0 1 .02-.022Z"/>
                </svg>
              </a>
              <span *ngIf="payment.status == true" class="text-success">
                -
              </span> 
            </td>
          </ng-container>
          <!-- details Column-->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="details">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> - </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let payment">
              <a [routerLink]="['/admin/payments/details',payment.id]"  matTooltip="Detalles de la factura" matTooltipClass = "tooltipPer">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z"/>
                </svg>
              </a>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
        
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      
          <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
          <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
            <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No encontrado "{{input.value}}"</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 50]" aria-label="Select page of users"></mat-paginator>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

y este es mi componente  ts

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription} from 'rxjs';
//MATERIAL 
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
//SERVICES
import { InvoiceService } from 'src/app/services/invoice.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
//models
import { Payment } from 'src/app/models/payment';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-paymentlist',
  templateUrl: './paymentlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./paymentlist.component.css']
})
export class PaymentlistComponent implements AfterViewInit,OnDestroy {
  public subscriptions:Subscription [] = [];
  public payments:Payment [] = [];
  //material
  public displayedColumns: string[] = ['date','name', 'client_ci', 'products', 'sub_total','total','status','confirm','details'];
  public dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<Payment>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

  constructor(
    private _paymentService:InvoiceService,
    private _route:Router,
  ){
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.getPayments();
  }
  ngOnDestroy():void{
    this.subscriptions.forEach(sub=>{ sub.unsubscribe() });
  }
  getPayments(){
    this.subscriptions.push(this._paymentService.allInvoices().subscribe(
      response =>{
        if(response){
          this.payments = response.payments;
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.payments);
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
          console.log(this.dataSource.sort,this.sort)
        }
      },
      err =>{ 
        console.error(err);
      }
    ));
  }
  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
}
```

solo me da los resultados cuando filtro por los valores numeros pero los nombres no los encuentra por ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el modelo que estoy usando

```js
import { Customer } from "./customer";
import { ProductPayment } from "./productPayment";

export class Payment{
  constructor(
    public id:number,
    public payment_type:string,
    public iva:number,
    public sub_total:number,
    public total:number,
    public status:boolean,
    public createdAt:any,
    public updatedAt:any,
    public customer_id:number,
    public client:Customer,
    public product_payments: ProductPayment[]
  ){}
}
```

tambien me causa errores en el sort no funciona no se que estoy haciendo mal en otras tablas me funciona perfectamente, no se si es por el la complejidad del modelo que algunas propiedades son objetos tambien que a su vez tienen otros objetos como propiedades  agradezcco de ante mano la ayuda un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en este caso no te esta funcionando el filtro con el nombre del cliente, porque el campo *client* es un objeto.

Por defecto el *dataSource* para aplicar los filtros, lo que hace es combinar todos los valores del objeto de cada fila en un string, contra el que luego compara el valor del string que pasas como *filter*.

Por ejemplo el objeto:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Manuel',
  status: true,
}
```

Quedaría como `"1◬manuel◬true"`

En tu caso como el campo client apunta a otro objeto:

```
{
  client: {
    name: 'Mariano'
  }
}
```

al pasarlo a string queda como `[object object]`

Para que te funcione el filtro en este caso tienes dos opciones:

1.- Asignarle al dataSource un *filterPredicate* personalizado, que es una función del tipo.

```
(data: T, filter: string) => boolean
```

Donde `data` es el objeto de cada fila y `filter` es el string que pasas como filtro. En el cuerpo de esta funcion tendrás que definir la lógica de comparación personalizada, devolviendo `true` o `false` cuando el filtro sea aplicable a dicha fila. Por ejemplo si solo quisieras aplicar el filtro al nombre del cliente en tu caso tendrias que definir una funcion similar a esta:

```
dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: Payment, filter: string) => data.client.name.includes(filter)
```

2.- O la segunda opción es transformar los objetos que le pasas al *dataSource* para que los campos por los que quieras filtrar no estén dentro de objetos anidados, para que así funcione el *filterPredicate* por defecto.

un saludo

Comment: el codigo que me colocas deberia ponerlo debajo de la asignacion  de  "this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();" este troso ? en la funcion del filtro ?

Comment: No hace falta reasignarla cada vez. Con que la asignes cuando generas el datasource es suficiente. En tu caso en el subscribe del metodo `getPayments`.

Comment: me funciono pero sabes tengo el mismo problema con el paginator como se haria en ese caso ? gracias dde antemano

Comment: Si haces un console.log del paginator antes de asignarlo verás que te logea `undefined`, porque si no veo mal, lo tienes dentro del `*ngIf` de cuando hay `payments`. Cuando estás asignando el paginator al datasource, todavía no se ha actualizado la vista para mostrar los elementos de ese *ngIf, por lo que el @ViewChild tampoco tiene la referencia al paginator. Las dos soluciones más sencillas serían: sacar el paginator del ngIf y ocultarlo con estilos hasta que haya resultados, o meter la asignacion en un timeout, `setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator);`

Comment: gracias eres un maquina te debo 2